# Angular2 Routes with electron not working

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, electron

My app in angular2 was fully functional loading component after component. When I tried to use it with electron everything went downhill. I keep trying to follow different tutorials, but they are not working for me. Can anyone point me in the direction on why this is not working please.

index.html inside app/

```
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>QuizzUmmah</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  </head>
<body>
 <h1>Index On</h1>
 <app></app>

 <script src="../node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
 <script src="../build/common.js"></script>
 <script src="../build/angular2.js"></script>
 <script src="../build/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

App.ts inside app/start/

```
///<reference path="../../node_modules/angular2/typings/browser.d.ts"/>
import {bootstrap} from "angular2/platform/browser";
import { Component, provide } from "angular2/core";
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, RouteConfig, Router, ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from 'angular2/router';
import { APP_BASE_HREF,HashLocationStrategy, Location, LocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';
import { Control } from 'angular2/common';
import { HomeComponent } from '../home/home.component';

@RouteConfig([
 { path: '/home', component: HomeComponent, name: 'HomeComponent' },
 { path: '/**', redirectTo: ['HomeComponent'] }
])

@Component({
  selector: "app",
  template:`<h1>Working</h1>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>`,
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
 })

 export class App {}

 bootstrap(App, [
  ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
  provide(APP_BASE_HREF, { useValue: '/' }),
  provide(LocationStrategy, { useClass: HashLocationStrategy })
 ]);
```

HomeComponent inside app/home

```
  import { Component} from '@angular/core';
  import { Router } from '@angular/router';

  @Component({
    selector: 'app-home',
    template:  `<h1>Home is working</h1>`,
   })
   export class HomeComponent{

   constructor(){}

   }
```

Comment: what are your errors? if it has to do with not being able to find any of your scripts ie C://build/app.js try changing your <base href="/"> TO <base href="./">

Answer (score 1):

Just change the body of the *index.html* file like below. Use a `<base>` tag inside the body without the "/" symbol and try it.

```
<body>
    <base href="">
    <h1>Index On</h1>
    <app></app>
    <script src=".....></script>
</body>
```

Comment: I added the <base> tag in to the <head> section. It solved my problem that my Single Page Application always shows a white page when I tried to use a relative link with an <a> tag.

Comment: what is your Router array.. ? please can you send that with <a ..... ></a>

Comment: i tried several combinations with "#/foo" "/foo" "foo" and so on. All without success. But it was the special case that my SPA was embedded in Electron. With the empty <base> Tag it's all fine and working perfect.